# ZF2 Skeleton Application Without Virtual Host?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, virtualhost

I am new in ZF2. I have developed my small application in my local computer using virtual host.I want to run this site without virtual host.

My Folder Directory Structure is like this:

```
-ProjectName  
  -config
  -module
  -vendor
    - zendframework
  -public
    - css
    - img
    - JS
    - index.php
```

Index.php File:

```
<?php
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

// Decline static file requests back to the PHP built-in webserver
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server' && is_file(__DIR__ . parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH))) {
    return false;
}

// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

For access CSS Or Image all time I used $this->basePath() prepend to fetch it.

My application is works fine if I write URL like this:

localhost/projectname/public/modulename

but I doesnt want to use public in url. How can I call my project without "Public" in url.

Answer (score 0):

Place your folder `ProjectName` somewhere outside of web server document root and make symbolic link to public folder in it.

For example, if your web server document root:

```
/var/www/html
```

place your project to

```
/var/www
```

and make simlink

```
/var/www/html/ProjectName -> ../ProjectName/public
```

If you work under the Windows OS, it is in much the same way.

For your case make this steps:

1. Open command prompt as administrator
2. Suppose your user name is USERNAME, your wamp disk placement is D:. Execute commands:

   `C:\Users\USERNAME> d:`

   `D:\> cd wamp\www`

   `D:\wamp\www> mklink /D projectname D:\wamp\www\projectname\public`

After that you may try to access your project by URL:

```
http:\\localhost\projectname
```

["NTFS symbolic link" on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)

Comment: I cant understand what you think. Can you please give me explantion?

Comment: Give me some information: your operating system, your web server's document root, your project placement path.

Comment: But you say that "I have developed my small application in my local computer using virtual host".

Comment: Sorry. I give reply for live site.ok np.i am giving you my local root path: drive name:/wamp/www/projectname. Operating system:windows 7

Comment: Its return Invalid Switch - "D".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44133/discussion-between-chirag-and-microbe)