# ZF2 Apache install on VPS witout creating Virtual Host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I want to install my ZF2 application on a VPS server without support for Virtual Host. I´m using a simple application based on ZendApplicationSkeleton.

I´m using the default `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

All solution I´ve found in SO does not work for me. They may fit ZF1, but not ZF2:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992237/zend-framework-application-without-virtual-hosts)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858591/make-zend-framework-2-work-without-virtual-host)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992237/zend-framework-application-without-virtual-hosts)

[Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812882/zf2-skeleton-application-without-virtual-host)

My application is in a folder named `/var/www/html/testapp`.

The main page is loaded once I type`localhost/testapp/public` on the browser. Also my module is loaded if I type `localhost/testapp/module`, but navigation does not work.

Ie: in the main page, I´ve created a button like:

```
<a href="/module/index">Go To Module</a>
```

But if I click on it I navigate to `localhost/login/index` showing `Not Found`, not to the correct `module/index.phtml` page.

Help appreciated with that.

Comment: What hosting service do you use? I can hardly believe that there is no possibility to somehow setup the folder you want to serve?

Comment: Looks like you have some kind of login/authentication check that redirects to localhost/login/index when the link /module/index is access.  Check your  login/authenticator and make sure the redirect is disabled if you don't need login (dev purpose)

Comment: Also, for ZF2 application, the public folder should be the root directory of your webapp.  So you will need to configure your VHOST to use /var/www/html/testapp/public as the DocumentRoot.  Also since your app is located in /var/www/html, the default Apache configuration may also be trying to serve the files directly, which may result to urls that will not match any of your ZF2 route definitions.  It is probably best to move your app outside of the /var/www/html directory so that all private configurations/files cannot be access accidentally if something ever happens to your server config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with server configuration. Since your app is in a sub-folder, the link is wrong. It would need to be something like

```
<a href="/testapp/public/module/index">Go To Module</a>
```

for it to work. However, `public/` should never appear in you URLs. With things setup this way you are allowing users to view files outside your app's web root, which is a potential security risk (and results in ugly URLs).

The solution to this is to setup a separate vhost for your ZF2 app, which has a DOCUMENT ROOT pointing at the app's public folder. If you are having problems with this, post that as your question; or if you can explain why this isn't possible perhaps we can advise further.

Comment: @Wilt: I'm not sure what you're suggesting by simply linking to the ZF2 tutorial. Using a vhost is the real solution here. If that's what you're suggesting then we both agree. The example link I gave was just to explain why what the OP currently has doesn't work.

Comment: Fair enough. You'll see I'd posted a comment on your other answer agreeing with you. I've edited my answer here to make it clearer what the real solution is.

Comment: I removed my comments and upvoted, could you still remove "has nothing to do with server configuration" because it actually has everything to do with this...